# Install/Update a package on RHEL5 from CentOSPlus repo with same package existing in RHN

Tags: centos, postfix, yum, rhel5

I'm trying to install postfix with MySQL on RHEL5
but the repos from the rhnplugin are overriding it even if i have an exclude line in the rhnplugin.conf file

My goal is to only use the CentOSPlus repo for postfix and the rest use RHN

This is my rhnplugin.conf file

```
[main]
enabled = 1
gpgcheck = 1

[base]
exclude=postfix

[update]
exclude=postfix
```

and this is my CentOS-Base.repo file

```
[centosplus]
enabled=1
includepkgs=postfix
name=CentOS-5 - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=5&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
```

It works fine if I set `enabled=0` in my rhnplugin.conf file but my goal is not to disable that repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your rhnplugin.conf:

```
[rhel-x86_64-server-5]
exclude=postfix
```

Assuming "rhel-x86_64-server-5".  Adjust that repo according to your RHEL version.
(`yum repolist enabled` will show the enabled repos on your system)

Then install postfix:

```
yum install postfix
```

Comment: and you don't need the "base" and "update" sections in your rhnplugin.conf - those are for CentOS.